# Excluding fields with django-dilla

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to find a way to exclude some fields on a model with django-dilla meta classes. Never used django-dilla before.

My code look kind of like this:

```
class DillaController:
    models = ('Model2', 'Model1')

class Model1(models.Model):
    class Dilla:
        field_extras = {
            'field1': {'word_range': (2,5)},
        }
        ## HOW DO I EXCLUDE FIELDS HERE?
    [...]
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    field2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    excluded_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey('Model2', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Model2(models.Model):
    [...]
```

I'm still looking around. If I find something, I will update.

Thnx.

A.

edit: typo

Answer (score 0):

Found the proper documentation here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dilla/r17

In short, excluded fields should be provided inside the model's Dilla meta class.

```
class Dilla:
    [...]
    skip_fields = ('hash', 'user',)
```